# Where to tell Angular that my <html> direction should be right to left?

Tags: angular

I am using version 4 of Angular, I need to have a right to the left page, I prefer to set that in `html dir` attribute.

Like so:

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

But the basic page is getting made by Angular itself, so I don't see any html tag to add my direction there, anyway?

Comment: *"the basic page is getting made by Angular itself, anyway?"* - what? You create the `index.html` yourself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No sir, I mean I don't know where should I add it. I think the question is clear

Comment: From your previous question you're using [tag:angular-cli], so have you tried looking in `src/index.html`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's funny :) Thanks a lot.. I found it